# Nordic characters å, ø and æ not detected by azure b2c custom policy

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am using migration to create users in azure b2c from the legacy database. I have some users with nordic characters ***å, ø***, and ***æ*** in their username. I was able to create the users in azure b2c and when I search for users with graph API I see the username has those characters in it.

I have created a custom policy for logging in. It works for all the users with regular English alphabet uesrname. But, when trying to log the user with nordic characters in, it says account not detected. Somehow the username with nordic characters didn't match with the input provided.

For example, if the username is ***pål*** in azure b2c, correct input of username ***pål*** and password won't work but username ***pal*** would work.

How can I allow nordic username input to log in with custom policy?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using the latest version of the HTML Page Layout? As mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout#self-asserted-page-selfasserted version 2.1.2 fixed the localization encoding issue for languages.

Always use latest layout version in your policies.

Comment: Actually, the issue is with username login. The UI localization is working fine. I don't think Microsoft allows language characters in username but I was curious because I was able to create users with Nordic characters in b2c tenant but not use during login. Even if the user is already migrated, b2c login does not detect the user from the policy.